# Singleton Design Pattern cannot assign value final variable instance

Tags: java, android, singleton, final

I am trying to use the **Singleton design pattern** in ItemControl, but Android Studio says that I **cannot assign a value to final variable 'instance'**. How can I compile my code if the variable must be static final?

```
public final class ItemControl {
    private final Map<Long, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static final ItemControl instance;

    private ItemControl() { }

    public static synchronized ItemControl getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ItemControl();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        itemMap.put(item.getId(), item);
    }

    public List<Item> retrieveItems() {
        if(itemMap.isEmpty()) {
            List<Item> items = carregarItems();
            if(items != null) {
                for(Item item : items) {
                    itemMap.put(item.getId(), item);
                }
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(itemMap.values());
    }

    private List<Item> carregarItems() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        Item.Builder livroBuilder = new Item.Builder(System.nanoTime(), "Java for Beginners")
                .setAno(2013).setAutor("Glauber Rocha").setQuantidade(3)
                .setDescricao("Livro para programadores iniciantes.");

        Item.Builder revistaBuilder = new Item.Builder(System.nanoTime(), "Geek on the table")
                .setAno(2013).setAutor("Robson Duarte").setQuantidade(2)
                .setDescricao("Revista para geeks.");

        items.add(livroBuilder.build());
        items.add(revistaBuilder.build());

        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: why you need to be these variable static and final

Comment: Singleton design pattern demands it. Or not?

Comment: not you don't require it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Android Studio. 
See, you have the variable `instance` which has been declared final.  And its being assigned in `getInstance()`. So since its final you cannot assign it anywhere but there itself.

So do this:
`private static final ItemControl instance = new ItemControl();`

And in `getInstance()` return that variable

```
public static ItemControl getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. I did it. It is working now. How can I do that using enum? I read the topic below, but I didn't understand it. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You declared

```
private static final ItemControl instance;
```

Since `instance` is `final` you can not assign a value to `instance` in the method `getInstance()`. It must be assigned when it is declared, in the constructor, or in a initialization block.

That being said, consider implementing your singleton as a `enum`. See [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java?rq=1) if you can not get rid of it all together.

Comment: I did it. It is working now. But I did it not using enum because I didn't understand how to do that using enum...

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize instance when you declare it:

```
private static final ItemControl instance = new ItemControl();
```

Comment: but I want to have control of this instance... I want to have only one instance of an ItemControl object... and it must be accessible to all parts of my app

Comment: Then you can make the instance variable `public static final` and you can access the instance by calling `ItemControl.instance`. Since it's static, it's defined at the class level not the object level so there will only ever be one instance.

Comment: You can also have a getter for the instance like Uday describes

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. But I did in the pre-java1.5 way. I didn't understand how to do the same using 'enum'. How can I do the same singleton pattern using enum? I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java), but I didn't understand.

```
public final class ItemControl {
    private final Map<Long, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static final ItemControl instance = new ItemControl();

    private ItemControl() {
        if(instance != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ItemControl já foi instanciado.");
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ItemControl getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        itemMap.put(item.getId(), item);
    }

    public List<Item> retrieveItems() {
        if(itemMap.isEmpty()) {
            List<Item> items = carregarItems();
            if(items != null) {
                for(Item item : items) {
                    itemMap.put(item.getId(), item);
                }
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(itemMap.values());
    }

    private List<Item> carregarItems() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        Item.Builder livroBuilder = new Item.Builder(System.nanoTime(), "Java for Beginners")
                .setAno(2013).setAutor("Glauber Rocha").setQuantidade(3)
                .setDescricao("Livro para programadores iniciantes.");

        Item.Builder revistaBuilder = new Item.Builder(System.nanoTime(), "Geek on the table")
                .setAno(2013).setAutor("Robson Duarte").setQuantidade(2)
                .setDescricao("Revista para geeks.");

        items.add(livroBuilder.build());
        items.add(revistaBuilder.build());

        return items;
    }
}
```